# Write to Azure VM from Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure SQL database which has a stored procedures that outputs data in CSV format that I would like to write to a folder on an Azure VM.

Can anyone recommend how I might be able to do it?

Comment: Azure provides platform as a service which is a cloud service. Go through the azure APIs.

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options to get data out of sql and into a CSV:

**Powershell**

It's free, built in to every Windows Azure VM, and pretty easy to use. The two commandlets you're going to want to use are Invoke-Sqlcmd and Export-CSV.

I found a quick example [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/cjsommercom/2015/04/28/using-powershell-to-export-sql-data-to-csv-how-well-does-it-perform/).

**SSIS**

If your Azure VM is running a SQL instance, you could create a quick SSIS package that calls the procedure and dumps the output into a CSV.

**sqlcmd**

Again, if your Azure VM has SQL on it you could call sqlcmd.exe to spit out your CSV file.

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer.database.windows.net 
       -d yourdatabase -E -Q "EXEC usp_yourProcedure" 
       -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 4000
```

Choose the one that best fits your limitations. If you're not running SQL on that VM, Powershell, or some custom programming will be needed.